# How to export GridBagLayout content into csv file (or even Excel)?

Tags: java, csv, gridbaglayout

I have created GUI using Java and Swing. I have used GridBagLayout which is full of JLabel instances.

I have just texts (JLabels) in gridbaglayout, no other GUI components like JButton, JTextField etc..

Is there any existing solution how could I export content in GridBagLayout into CSV file?
Or if I want to presave alignment and fonts of components, is there any Java Excel API that could do this from GridBagLayout out of the box?

thanks for help

Comment: how can you possible get "alignment" and "fonts" into a plain text file?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right, I was thinking about creating Excel stylesheet. I edited my question.